# Onclicklistener Return To Fragment From Activity Not Working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to return to my main fragment from an activity when I click on an item in my list view, I also want it to pass back some text to the view. Unfortunately I have not been able to do it successfully as of yet and the code I am posting below is giving an error on "return fragobj;" saying that it:

> Cannot return a value from a method with a void result type

ActivityView:

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DevicesList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DeviceListAdapter dlAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listType;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listIcon;
    private ListView gridView;
    private String type;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_list);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        String message = bundle.getString("devicetype");
        type = message;
       // Toast.makeText(this, "DEBUGTYPE: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setTitle("Choose Your Device");



        prepareList();
        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        dlAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(DevicesList.this, listType, listIcon);


        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.GridViewDeviceList);
        gridView.setAdapter(dlAdapter);
        dlAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("device", dlAdapter.getItem(position));
                SearchScreen fragobj = new SearchScreen();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
                return fragobj;

            }
        });
    }

    public void prepareList() {
        listType = new ArrayList<String>();

if(type.equals("iphone")) {
    listType.add("iPhone 7");
    listType.add("iPhone 6S");
    listType.add("iPhone 6");
    listType.add("iPhone 5S");
    listType.add("iPhone 5");
    listType.add("iPad Pro");
    listType.add("iPad");
    listType.add("iPad Mini");
    listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("iPhone Devices");
}

else if(type.equals("android")){
    listType.add("Samsung S7");
    listType.add("Samsung S6");
    listType.add("Samsung S5");
    listType.add("Samsung Galaxy Mini");
    listType.add("Nexus Pro");
    listType.add("HTC One");
    listType.add("Google Pixel");
    listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Android Devices");
}

     else if(type.equals( "windows")) {
            listType.add("windows 10");
            listType.add("windows 8");
            listType.add("windows 7");
            listType.add("Other");

        setTitle("Windows PC");

        }

    else if(type.equals("mac")) {
            listType.add("iMac Pro");
            listType.add("iMac");
            listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Apple Mac PC");

        }

    else if(type.equals ("console")) {
            listType.add("Xbox One");
            listType.add("Xbox 360");
            listType.add("PS4");
            listType.add("PS4 Pro");
            listType.add("Nintendo Switch");
            listType.add("Nintendo Wii U");
            listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Consoles");

        }

    else if(type.equals ("laptop")) {
            listType.add("windows 10");
            listType.add("windows 8");
            listType.add("windows 7");
            listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Laptops");

        }

    else if(type.equals ("camera")) {
            listType.add("Nikon");
            listType.add("FujiFilm");
            listType.add("Sony");
            listType.add("Olympus");
            listType.add("Kodak");
            listType.add("Leica");
            listType.add("Pentax");
            listType.add("Ricah");
            listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Camera");

        }

    else if(type.equals ("printer")) {
            listType.add("Cannon");
            listType.add("Hewlett Packard");
            listType.add("Xerox");
            listType.add("Epson");
            listType.add("Toshiba");
            listType.add("Dell");
            listType.add("Other");

    setTitle("Printers");

        }
        listIcon = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }
}
```

MainView:

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap.TAG;

public class SearchScreen extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication";

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private GridViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> listType;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listIcon;
    private String repairtype;
    private GridView gridView;

    private TextView tv;

    private Button contBtn;
    private Button googleLocBtn;
    private Button devicepicker;
    private Button gpsBtn;
    private boolean setGPSloc = false;

    private Location mLocation;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;

    private TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    private TextView mLongitudeTextView;
    private TextView tv2;

    Double longitude;
    Double latitude;

    public static SearchScreen newInstance(){
        SearchScreen fragment = new SearchScreen();
        return fragment;
    }

    public SearchScreen(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        checkLocation();

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            //String device = intent.getStringExtra("device");
            //String device = bundle.getString("device");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NODEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else

        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DEVICESELECTED: " + intent.getStringExtra("device"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

         tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);




        prepareList();
        repairtype ="";

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_TextDateTime);
        btn_date = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_datePicker);

        btn_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDate();
            }
        });

        contBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        contBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Latitude: " + latitude + "Longitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TechnicianListView.class);
                intent.putExtra("type", repairtype);
                intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
                intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gpsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    tv2.setText("" + getMyPosAddress(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude()));
                latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

            }
        });


        tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById((R.id.textView));


        updateTextLabel();


        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), listType, listIcon);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DEBUG " + mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                repairtype = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            }
        });

        googleLocBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.googleLocBtn);
        googleLocBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findPlace(v.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
            }
        });

        devicepicker = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.devicepick);
        devicepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevicePicker.class);
               // intent.putExtra("message", "test");
                startActivity(intent);

              //  devicepicker.setText(getId("devicetype"));
            }
        });


        return view;
    }



    //Calling method DateFormat and Calendar
    DateFormat formatDateTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Creating Vars
    private TextView text;
    private Button btn_date;


    private void updateDate() {
        new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), d, dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }


    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateTextLabel();
        }
    };


    private void updateTextLabel() {
        text.setText(formatDateTime.format(dateTime.getTime()));
    }


    public void prepareList() {
        listType = new ArrayList<String>();

        listType.add("di1");
        listType.add("iphonescreen");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");
        listType.add("placeholder");

        listIcon = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        listIcon.add(R.drawable.camerabrokenicon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.screenrepairicon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
        listIcon.add(R.drawable.placeholdericon);
    }

    public void testBtn(View v) {
       // tv.setText("Welcome");

    }

    public void findPlace(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent =
                    new PlaceAutocomplete
                            .IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this.getContext(), data);
                Log.e("Tag", "Place: " + place.getAddress() + place.getPhoneNumber());

                ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView))
                        .setText("" + place.getName());

                latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                Log.e("Tag", "Latitude: " + latitude + "longitude: " + longitude);


            } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        super.onStart();
        if (client != null) {
            client.connect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        client.disconnect();
    }


    private String getMyPosAddress(double dbLat, double dbLon) {
        String addressString = "No address found";
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<android.location.Address> gclist ;

            gclist =  gc.getFromLocation(dbLat, dbLon, 1);


            if (gclist.size() > 0) {
                android.location.Address address = gclist.get(0);

                addressString = "" + address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getAdminArea();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return addressString;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           showAlert();
            return;
        }
        startLocationUpdates();
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {
            latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        }
        else {

        }


    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i("LOCCCC", "loc failed");
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        else{
            Log.i("LOCCCC", "loc ok");
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location!= null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        else {
            String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                    Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                    Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

            latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use MyGeek")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `OnItemClickListener`. `onClick()` returns `void` but you are trying to return a fragment. Here is a more standard way to invoke a fragment:

**In your activity:**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        SearchScreen fragobj = SearchScreen.newInstance(dlAdapter.getItem(position));
        // ...additional processing
    }
});
```

**In your fragment:**

```
public SearchScreen() {
    // Null constructor as required by Android
}

public static SearchScreen newInstance(String device){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    SearchScreen fragment = new SearchScreen();
    bundle.putString("device", device);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle;
    String device;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bundle = getArguments();
    device = bundle.getString("device");
    // ...and so on...
}
```

You can also take a look at [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) and [Using newInstance() to Instantiate a Fragment](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html) for more information.